# Python code to write XML strange way to close the elements

Tags: python

I have a python code that write a XML file. The commands I use are similar to this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import json
import csv
import random

data = ET.Element('DemoXML')
elementorderrequest = ET.SubElement(data, 'OrderRequest')

element0items = ET.SubElement(elementorderrequest, 'Items')
element0itemline1 = ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item lineNumber="1"')

element0unitprice1 = ET.SubElement(element0itemline1, 'UnitPrice')
element0unitprice1.text = “51.09”

b_xml = ET.tostring(data)
 
with open("items2.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b_xml)
```

The problem is in specific with the elements as ‘element0itemline1’. Check how it closes the element in the resulting file:

```
<Items>
    <Item lineNumber="1">
        <UnitPrice>51.09</UnitPrice>
    </Item lineNumber="1">
</Items>
```

The problem is the server rejects this way to close the element:

```
</Item lineNumber="1">
```

The server works if is entered like this:

```
</Item>
```

In other words a resulting file like this would be accepted:

```
<Items>
    <Item lineNumber="1">
        <UnitPrice>51.09</UnitPrice>
    </Item>
</Items>
```

How can be configured the python code or the element there to give `</Item>` and NOT `</Item lineNumber="1">`

I entered like this:

```
element0itemline1 = ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item', 'lineNumber="1"')
```

But gives the error:

```
   element0itemline1 = ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item', 'lineNumber="1"')
TypeError: SubElement() argument 3 must be dict, not str
```

Then how can be solved?

Comment: your `SubElement` needs a comma between the element name and its attribute. as it is now, the name is `Item lineNumber="1"` not `Item`.. ie `ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item', 'lineNumber="1"')`

Comment: `ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item lineNumber="1"')` The entire second argument, `Item lineNumber="1"` in this case, is being interpreted as the tag name...

Comment: I entered like that and I receive this error: “    element0itemline1 = ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item', 'lineNumber="1"')
TypeError: SubElement() argument 3 must be dict, not str”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of the issue is that `SubElement()` is interpreting your string as the entire name of the element.  You need to pass in the attributes as parameters.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = ET.Element('DemoXML')
elementorderrequest = ET.SubElement(data, 'OrderRequest')
element0items = ET.SubElement(elementorderrequest, 'Items')
element0itemline1 = ET.SubElement(element0items, 'Item', {"lineNumber":"1"})
element0unitprice1 = ET.SubElement(element0itemline1, 'UnitPrice')
element0unitprice1.text = "51.09"

b_xml = ET.tostring(data)
 
with open("items2.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b_xml)
```

generate a file for me:

```
<DemoXML>
  <OrderRequest>
    <Items>
      <Item lineNumber="1">
        <UnitPrice>51.09</UnitPrice>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </OrderRequest>
</DemoXML>
```